# How do I calculate and determine the area at which the div must be dropped?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am building a drag and drop application purely in Javascript. I have coded the drag part where the element can be dragged and dropped randomly in the page. Now, I have built a drop zone that contains 9 boxes(divs) wherein 9 divs must be dropped. I can't think of an approach that will help me accomplish this task. I am thinking of making those divs 'absolute' and re-build them use top & left attributes. But how should I proceed further? How will the div that I drag i.e onmousedown will come to know that onmouseup it should drop at the specified location. Example: If I select a div numbered 1, it should drop at target numbered 1.

Here's the Javascript I am using for selecting and dragging:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('block1');
    var mover = false, x, y, posx, posy, first = true;
    el.onmousedown = function() {
        mover = true;
    };
    el.onmouseup = function() {
        mover = false;
        first = true;
    };
    el.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (mover) {
            if (first) {
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
                first = false;
            }
            posx = e.pageX - x;
            posy = e.pageY - y;
            this.style.left = posx + 'px';
            this.style.top = posy + 'px';
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have the targets recognize a "onmouseenter" and set a Boolean to be true for that target, then set it to false "onmouseleave". then "onmouseup" check all of the booleans and if div1 has been dropped and target1 is true then div1 position = target position.

I know this is a pseudo code answer but its just my thought process on ho to solve the problem.